# Cannot install @testing-library/jest-dom with Node 16.2.0

Tags: npm, jestjs, next.js, node-modules, react-testing-library

Deleted the node modules and dropped the package-lock file. After that try to do npm install and it results in the below error. Node version is 16.2.0. Ran npm cache clean --force as well.

npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: jest-matcher-utils@28.1.1
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: jest-matcher-utils@28.1.1
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=17.0.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"7.13.0","node":"v16.2.0"}

Following is the config in .npmrc file
engine-strict=true
legacy-peer-deps=true

Even tried uninstalling jest but was faced with the same error

Here is the dev dependency
"devDependencies": {
"@next/bundle-analyzer": "^12.0.7",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
"@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
"autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
"cross-env": "^7.0.3",
"eslint": "7.28.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "7.24.0",
"husky": "^7.0.1",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"lint-staged": "11.0.0",
"msw": "^0.38.1",
"postcss": "^8.2.15",
"prettier": "^2.4.1",
"tailwindcss": "^2.1.2"
}

Comment: Can you switch to at least node 16.10? It is suggested in the error message

Comment: @SonNguyen The production docker image has node version 16.2.0 and we are trying to update the lock file and stick to the npm ci command. Any other solution?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't bump the Node.js version to 16.10 in the Docker image?